# Cannot connect to Oracle DB from centos

Tags: java, oracle, centos, ojdbc

I have a java code that connects to an oracle database.
It was working fine in the windows machine as well as Mac. But when I try to run the code from an openstack machine (running on centos) I am getting error. From debugging, I found that the machine is not even connecting to the database.

Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Connection requested");
        String selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME";
        Connection connection = getConnection("username","password");
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
            ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Connection successful");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Connection getConnection(String username, String password) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("classname");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url",username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection error\n" + e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection error\n" + e);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection acquired");

        return connection;
    }


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/net/ns/Message
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.disconnect(NSProtocol.java:470)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:515)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:595)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.dal.OracleDBConnection.getConnection(OracleDBConnection.java:289)
    at com.data.format.FeedFormatter.getHistory(FeedFormatter.java:167)
    at com.data.FeedGenerator.generateJson(FeedGenerator.java:143)
    at com.data.FeedGenerator.main(FeedGenerator.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.net.ns.Message
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I had exported my code as a runnable jar. Therefore the jdbc drivers should be available. What am I missing here?

Edit: As suggested in the comments, I have looked in the jar I created and I can see that the `Message.class` exists. And this jar is running fine in OSX, while not at all connecting in CentOS. I can see `Connection Requested` and nothing after that for minutes.

Comment: *I had exported my code as a runnable jar. Therefore the jdbc drivers should be available*. It all depends on how you did that, what the Manifest file of the jar contains, where the jars are located, and how you execute the jar. The exception you posted doesn't look at all like a connection problem. It looks a lot like a classpath problem.

Comment: "the jdbc drivers should be available", but obviously they are not. To make sure your jar is built correctly, open it with your favorite unzip utility and check if it contains a file `Message.class` under `oracle/net/ns` directory. If not your jar does not contain you jdbc driver.

Comment: @JB Nizet I ran the file as a jar from my mac and it's working. I've all the libs within the project itself and gave the option to export the dependencies with the jar.

Comment: @StephaneM yes, it does contain the class

Comment: @JBNizet I have other dependencies like apache poi in the same jar. And after exporting as a jar and running in centos, they don't throw any error. So I am wondering if I require something more than `ojdbc` to make this work. Do I need to install something in the machine?

Comment: I have seen this error in the past and it was caused by a malformed URL. Can you provide the URL that you're using?

Comment: @JeandeLavarene `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/xxx`

Comment: Try with the long URL format such as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))`